# Is there a free viewer for Adobe PageMaker file?

Tags: viewer

Trying to open a .p65 file (Adobe PageMaker) but I don't find anything to open it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that can open Pagemaker files is Pagemaker, afaik.

However, you can get a [free trial here](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=pagemaker&loc=en_us).  If you need ongoing support you may have to just buy a used copy on eBay or the like.